# Moving two rectangles at the same time with different keys Java

Tags: java, keylistener

Trying to moving two rectangles at the same time with different keys. Using KeyListener. I'm doing Pong Game in Java and have some troubles with this. If I try to move the first paddle, the second will not moving while I'm moving the first. Help me please with this problem. Maybe it will be fixed with multithreading?

Main class:

```
public class GameStart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }
}
```

Frame class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Frame extends JFrame{
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1200;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800;
    private final String TITLE = "Pong";
    Frame() {
        setTitle(TITLE);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setTitle(TITLE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();
        paintPanel.setFocusable(true);
        paintPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
        this.add(paintPanel);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Paint class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

class PaintPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    // holds the panel's insets
    Insets ins;
    private int RACKET_ONE_Y = 360;
    private final int RACKET_ONE_X = 160;
    private int RACKET_TWO_Y = 360;
    private final int RACKET_TWO_X = 1025;
    private final int SPEED = 50;
    private final int LOWEST_RACKET_POS = 60;
    private final int HIGHEST_RACKET_POS = 600;
    // Construct a panel.
    PaintPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    // Override the paintComponent() method.
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Always call the superclass method first.
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawBorders(g);
        drawMiddleLine(g);
        drawRacketOne(g);
        drawRacketTwo(g);

    }
    // drawing rackets
    private void drawRacketOne(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(RACKET_ONE_X, RACKET_ONE_Y, 15, 90);
    }
    private void drawRacketTwo(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(RACKET_TWO_X, RACKET_TWO_Y, 15, 90);
    }
    // game frame borders
    private void drawBorders(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(100, 50, 1000, 10);
        g.fillRect(100, 50, 10, 660);
        g.fillRect(100, 700, 1000, 10);
        g.fillRect(1090, 50, 10, 660);
    }
    // middle line
    private void drawMiddleLine(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        for (int i = 70; i < 672; i += 40) {
            g.fillRect(590, i, 10, 25);
        }
    }
    // moving rackets
    private void racketOneMoveUp(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            if (RACKET_ONE_Y > LOWEST_RACKET_POS) {
                RACKET_ONE_Y -= SPEED;
            }
        }
    }
    private void racketOneMoveDown(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            if (RACKET_ONE_Y < HIGHEST_RACKET_POS) {
                RACKET_ONE_Y += SPEED;
            }
        }
    }
    private void racketTwoMoveUp(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_O) {
            if (RACKET_TWO_Y > LOWEST_RACKET_POS) {
                RACKET_TWO_Y -= SPEED;
            }
        }
    }
    private void racketTwoMoveDown(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_L) {
            if (RACKET_TWO_Y < HIGHEST_RACKET_POS) {
                RACKET_TWO_Y += SPEED;
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        switch (key) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                racketOneMoveUp(e);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                racketOneMoveDown(e);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_O:
                racketTwoMoveUp(e);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_L:
                racketTwoMoveDown(e);
                break;
        }
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @WJS got it, added gif

Comment: [mre] means code.  And please do not post images of code.  Your code should be short and should compile with no errors.  At present, your code doesn't run.

Comment: Hello, in the `keyPressed` function you're checking if a key is pressed and you're doing the in the racketMove functions you should skip the second test. For example racketTwoMoveDown becomes :
`private void racketTwoMoveDown() { if (RACKET_TWO_Y < HIGHEST_RACKET_POS) {RACKET_TWO_Y += SPEED;}}`

But for your problem try print the key code to check how the function behave.

Comment: @WJS now it should compile. sorry for my incompetence

Comment: Did you try Googling for **java swing pong two player game**. It appears that many people have already written a _Pong_ game using _Swing_. Maybe it will help you resolve your problem if you see how the game was written by other people.

Comment: I reorganized you code slightly and see no problems moving both paddles at the same time.  Are you saying you cannot do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reorganized your code to fit in a single file (easier to debug that way).   I do not see the problem you are talking about as I am able to move both paddles at the same time.

Changes made.

- invoke via SwingUtilties.
- override `getPreferredSize()` in `PaintPanel` class
- set the size via `getPreferredSize` in the panel gives you a true size less the frame border thicknesses.
- pack the frame before setting to center
- made a `MyKeyListener` class that extends KeyAdapter - adapter classes have default empty methods so you don't have to explicitly add them.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Pong {
    
    private final String TITLE = "Pong";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Pong().start());
    }
    
    public void start() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);
        PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.setTitle(TITLE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        paintPanel.setFocusable(true);
        paintPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
        frame.add(paintPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}

class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
    
    // holds the panel's insets
    Insets ins;
    private int RACKET_ONE_Y = 360;
    private final int RACKET_ONE_X = 160;
    private int RACKET_TWO_Y = 360;
    private final int RACKET_TWO_X = 1025;
    private final int SPEED = 2;
    private final int LOWEST_RACKET_POS = 60;
    private final int HIGHEST_RACKET_POS = 600;
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1200;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800;
    private Map<String, Runnable> moves = new HashMap<>();
    
    // Construct a panel.
    PaintPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
    }
    
    // Override the paintComponent() method.
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Always call the superclass method first.
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawBorders(g);
        drawMiddleLine(g);
        drawRacketOne(g);
        drawRacketTwo(g);
        for (Runnable moveit : moves.values()) {
            moveit.run();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    }
    
    // drawing rackets
    private void drawRacketOne(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(RACKET_ONE_X, RACKET_ONE_Y, 15, 90);
    }
    
    private void drawRacketTwo(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(RACKET_TWO_X, RACKET_TWO_Y, 15, 90);
    }
    
    // game frame borders
    private void drawBorders(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(100, 50, 1000, 10);
        g.fillRect(100, 50, 10, 660);
        g.fillRect(100, 700, 1000, 10);
        g.fillRect(1090, 50, 10, 660);
    }
    
    // middle line
    private void drawMiddleLine(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        for (int i = 70; i < 672; i += 40) {
            g.fillRect(590, i, 10, 25);
        }
    }
    
    // moving rackets
    private void racketOneMoveUp(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            if (RACKET_ONE_Y > LOWEST_RACKET_POS) {
                RACKET_ONE_Y -= SPEED;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void racketOneMoveDown(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            if (RACKET_ONE_Y < HIGHEST_RACKET_POS) {
                RACKET_ONE_Y += SPEED;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void racketTwoMoveUp(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_O) {
            if (RACKET_TWO_Y > LOWEST_RACKET_POS) {
                RACKET_TWO_Y -= SPEED;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void racketTwoMoveDown(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_L) {
            if (RACKET_TWO_Y < HIGHEST_RACKET_POS) {
                RACKET_TWO_Y += SPEED;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
        
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            String ch =
                    Character.toString(e.getKeyChar()).toUpperCase();
            if (!moves.containsKey(ch)) {
            
                int key = e.getKeyCode();
                switch (key) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                        moves.put("W",
                                () -> racketOneMoveUp(e));
                        moves.remove("S");
//                  racketOneMoveUp(e);
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                        moves.put("S",
                                () -> racketOneMoveDown(e));
                        moves.remove("W");
//                  racketOneMoveDown(e);
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_O:
                        moves.put("O",
                                () -> racketTwoMoveUp(e));
                        moves.remove("L");
//                  racketTwoMoveUp(e);
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_L:
                        moves.put("L",
                                () -> racketTwoMoveDown(e));
                        moves.remove("O");
//                  racketTwoMoveDown(e);
                        break;
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, WJS. But have you tried to hold paddles control buttons? It still can't moving together, only if getting many clicks on button, withoud holding

Comment: If you click the buttons at the same time they will move together.  Are you talking about simply holding them down?

Comment: Yes, holding them. That was the problem

Comment: The  problem is that all events are handled on a single thread.  So you get conflict and one takes over since the other doesn't have time to be processed.    I modified the `PaintPanel` class to use a map to hold the current directions.  This map will be used to paint the current positions each time paint is invoked.  It's not perfect since there can be a delay in switching directions.  There are probably better alternatives but for now this is the best I can do.

Comment: Thank you very much, my friend. Best wishes to you :)